# Change ActiveX Control Button Caption with SelectionChange function

Tags: excel, vba

Looking through the similar questions, I cannot find any that pertain to using the SelectionChange function. The process is:
1) End user fills out the spreadsheet (Button caption reads "Send to Supervisor")
2) Supervisor reviews for Accuracy (If Approved -> Caption reads "Send to HR", Disapproved -> Caption reads "Send Back")
3) HR reviews for final approval (If Approved -> Caption reads "Print", Disapproved -> Caption reads "Send Back")

I'm trying to make use of the SelectionChange function, as the button caption is determined by whether or not the selection is Approved or Disapproved. However, I'm missing something because whether I code as an Intersect or simple If/ElseIf, it will not update the button caption. The latest iteration of the non-working code is:

```
    If Intersect(Target, Range("F38:G38")) = "DISAPPROVED" Then
        Sheets("Sheet").Button.Caption = "Send Back"
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F38:G38")) = "DISAPPROVED" And CBText = "ENGINEER" Then
        Sheets("Sheet").Button.Caption = "Send to Supervisor"
    End If
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F38:G38")) = "DISAPPROVED" And CBText = "SUPERVISOR" Then
        Sheets("Sheet").Button.Caption = "Send to HR"
    End If
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F38:G38")) = "DISAPPROVED" And CBText = "NO" Then
        Sheets("Sheet").Button.Caption = "Print"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Note: `Intersect(Target, Range("F38:G38")) = "DISAPPROVED"` will fail if both `F38` and `G38` are selected - unless you have a check that only one cell is selected and haven't included that in this snippet.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying. They are merged cells. I tried selecting only one cell or the other, but it did not make a difference.

Comment: If they are merged cells, then only `F38` can be selected.

Comment: @BigBen  I bet F38 and G38 are merged cells, which will probably throw more issues down the road too.  @OP I would suggest using a named range for those cells and also use `Intersect(Target, Me.Range("F38")) = "DISAPPROVED"`

Comment: ^ Nice guess @ZackE :)

Comment: To simplify the code too I would use a `Select Case` for values in that cell.  That way you can then use a `With` `End With` for the button caption.

Comment: Im sure @BigBen can come up with something a lot more elegant for a solution, but hopefully my answer below will help you get started and solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest something like this in the `Worksheet_Change` event and not the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event.  The `Option Compare Text` ignores the case sensitivity just in case the value in cell F38 could be something other than all uppercase.  Im guessing CBText is a text string from somewhere else in the code.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim CBText As String

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("F38")) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Intersect(Target, Me.Range("F38"))
            Case Is = "disapproved"
                Select Case CBText
                    Case Is = vbNullString: ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton1.Caption = "Send Back"
                    Case Is = "engineer": ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton1.Caption = "Send to Supervisor"
                    Case Is = "supervisor": ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton1.Caption = "Send to HR"
                    Case Is = "no": ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton1.Caption = "Print"
                End Select
        End Select
    End If

End Sub
```